# Given n numbers, show the highest and lowest number

Tags: javascript, numbers

I just started getting into programming and I have been trying to solve this puzzle, but unfortunately I couldn't find any answers related to this  anywhere, so here it goes:

1) Given n numbers (using prompt), show the highest and lowest numbers of the set.

```
var highest = 0, **lowest = 0**;

while(true) {
var num = prompt("Input a number");

  if(num == 0) {break;}

  if(num < 0) {
   alert("Input a valid number.");
  }

  if(num > highest) {
    highest = num;
  }

  **if(num < lowest) {
    lowest = num**

  }

}
document.write("The highest number is: " + highest + "<br>");
document.write("The lowest number is: " + lowest);
```

I know that the code is wrong, probably with the variable lowest, so I would be much obliged if someone helped me.

Comment: In your code `lowest` will never change as they cannot input a negative and `lowest`  starts at 0.

Comment: Oh true. I'm so used to returns after alerts...

Comment: `num` is string, so you need to convert it to a number before you compare it with `highest` and `lowest`.

Comment: Per Racil's comment, consider: `var num = ~~prompt("Input a number");` See various alternatives (eg. `parseInt`), and more information at https://coderwall.com/p/5tlhmw/converting-strings-to-number-in-javascript-pitfalls as there are differences in rules.

Comment: The input can't be negative because of the question(I failed to specify, but the question say to give this message if the user input a negative number)

I tried using parseInt, but no sucess there.

@pmkro Yeah, I know that it's wrong to assign the value 0 to the variable as the number 0 will always be the lowest one, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to convert to number every entered value, so you can use the object `Number` never use `parseInt` because this `4hhrh` will be converted to `4`.
- To avoid invalid values like letters, use the function `isNaN`.
- When an entered value is invalid, execute the statement `continue`.
- This statement gets the lowest value `lowest = num < lowest ? num : lowest;`.

```js
var highest = 0,
    lowest = Number.MAX_VALUE;

while (true) {
  var num = Number(prompt("Input a number"));

  if (num == 0) {
    break;
  }

  if (isNaN(num) || num < 0) {
    alert("Input a valid number.");
    continue
  }
  
    lowest = num < lowest ? num : lowest;
  
  if (num > highest) {
    highest = num;    
  }  

}
document.write("The highest number is: " + highest + "<br>");
document.write("The lowest number is: " + lowest);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a keyword (`var`, `let`, `const`) to every time you declare a new variable so you need `var lower = 0` and you'll need a semi colon separating your two declarations. Also you asterisks below are breaking the If statement. The following should work:

```
let highest = 0; let lowest = 999999;

while(true) {
let num = prompt("Input a number");

if(num == 0) {break;}

if(num < 0) {
  alert("Input a valid number.");
}

if(num > highest) {
  highest = num;
}

if(num < lowest) {
  lowest = num;
}
}
document.write("The highest number is: " + highest + "<br>");
document.write("The lowest number is: " + lowest);
```

Also, `lowest` can't be set to 0 since you'll never have a number lower than that in your program. I set it to 99999 but you would need to use whatever your upper bound is or perhaps `null`.

Furthermore, consider researching the difference between `var`, `let` and `const`.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to maybe set the lowest to a large number, but I think an even better idea is to leave them undefined.. Because if say the user types 0 on first input, you have a state that indicates such.

Below is your example code modified with a few tweaks, and extra sanity checks.

```js
var highest, lowest;

while(true) {
  var num = parseInt(prompt("Input a number, 0 - when done"), 10);

  if(num < 0 || isNaN(num)) {
    alert("Input a valid number.");
    continue;
  }
  
  if(num === 0) {break;}

  if(highest === undefined || num > highest) {
    highest = num;
  }

  if(lowest === undefined || num < lowest) {
    lowest = num;
  }
}

if (lowest === undefined) {
  document.write("No Numbers given");
} else {
  document.write("The highest number is: " + highest + "<br>");
  document.write("The lowest number is: " + lowest);
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can let the user leave the input-field empty in order to see the results:

```js
var highest,lowest;

while (true) {
  var num = parseInt(prompt("Input a number.  Leave empty to see results"));
  
  if (isNaN(num)) {break;}
  else if (num < 0) {alert("Negative values are not allowed");}
  else {
    if (num>highest || highest==undefined) {highest = num;}
    if (num<lowest || lowest==undefined) {lowest = num;}
  }
}
document.write("The highest number is: "+(highest!=undefined?highest:"-")+"<br>");
document.write("The lowest number is: "+(lowest!=undefined?lowest:"-"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to set `lowest` to the highest possible number to start with, and then also parse the prompt as an integer, and ensure that it's a valid number:

```
var highest = 0, lowest = Number.MAX_VALUE;
while(true) {
    var num = parseInt(prompt("Input a number"));
    if(num == 0) {
        break;
    }
    if(num < 0 || isNaN(num)) {
        alert("Input a valid number.");
        continue;
    }
    if(num > highest) {
        highest = num;
    }
    if(num < lowest) {
        lowest = num;
    }
}
document.write("The highest number is: " + highest + "<br>");
document.write("The lowest number is: " + lowest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you use zero to end, simply add a check for zero before you compare to `highest` and `lowest`. Also you should parse the value from string to number:

```js
var highest = 0, lowest = 0;

while (true) {
  var num = parseInt(prompt("Input a number, 0 - when done"), 10);

  if (num == 0) {
    break;
  }
  if (num < 0 || isNaN(num)) {
    alert("Input a valid number.");
    continue;
  }

  if (highest == 0 || num > highest) {
    highest = num;
  }

  if (lowest == 0 || num < lowest) {
    lowest = num;
  }

}
document.write("The highest number is: " + highest + "<br>");
document.write("The lowest number is: " + lowest);
```